# Planet spinning at 90 degrees

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, astrophysics

I'm creating a planet and I was wondering what would happen in its situation.

The planet's rotation axis is rotated 90 degrees, but still spins. Its gravity is twice than that of the Earth, and spins 24 times faster, so the surface gravity is 1/2 of Earth at the equator.

Is this even possible? If yes, would the spin slow down and stop? Would the planet re-orient? What would happen with plate tectonics and such?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87967/how-plausible-is-a-tilted-axis-planet-with-a-south-pole-constantly-facing-to If I understand your question correctly, I think it has already been asked.

Comment: Please note, edits to a question are not supposed to invalidate existing answers, if you have a different question to ask, please open a new thread.

Answer (score 4):

All the conditions you give do not fit together.

> It is tidally locked, and is rotated 90 degrees

If the body is in tidal locking, its axis of rotation is perpendicular to the plane containing the orbit, else it won't be tidally locked.

> [the planet] spins 24 times faster [than Earth]

Also this is hardly possible for a tidally locked body. Tidal locking implies that one revolution on its own axis takes as much as a revolution around the center of mass of the system. To orbit that fast I suspect the body would be too close to the other one to keep its integrity.

Comment: Ah. You're right. Thx. I was really looking for what would happen with the spin tho.